# SELECT and SELECT COALESCE

Tags: mysql, select, coalesce

I received wonderful help in answering a question yesterday that lead me to successfully use `SELECT COALESCE` in a `MySQL` database to replace a nested excel formula. What i'm now struggling with is using the `SELECT COALESCE` in conjunction with using the `SELECT` command in the same query. All my columns are coming from the same table `(best_estimate)` but what I would like to do is:

```
SELECT 'OFS_ID' from best_estimate
```

and also perform the following:

```
SELECT COALESCE(FINAL_TOTAL, INITIAL_TOTAL, CDSI_TOTAL, JCE_TOTAL,  0 ) AS my_value
FROM best_estimate
```

so the end result will result in two columns -

```
OFS_ID and MY_VALUE
```

I'm just not sure how to join these two different commands - I spent three hours working on it yesterday and I keep getting syntax errors saying that I can't use SELECT in that place in the query.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
SELECT OFS_ID,COALESCE(FINAL_TOTAL, INITIAL_TOTAL, CDSI_TOTAL, JCE_TOTAL, 0 ) AS my_value FROM best_estimate
```

Comment: I have not, will try it now!

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much Alexander - I will accept as my answer as soon as it lets me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT `OFS_ID`, COALESCE(FINAL_TOTAL, INITIAL_TOTAL, CDSI_TOTAL, JCE_TOTAL,  0 ) AS my_value
FROM best_estimate
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Ankit.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I *think* I understand now that COALESCE is an operator, so I'm selecting the result of the COALESCE operator acting on the fields in parentheses. My error in thinking was the COALESCE had to proceed the SELECT command immediately, and not that it needed to precede the columns I wanted to operate on.

Comment: exactly. COALESCE is just an an operator.